# Is it possible to use a custom domain with Windows Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We have a complex Azure setup...cloud services, websites, storage accounts, VM's...the whole shebang.

We have custom domains to all of these things and they work great, but I can't find any documentation on setting up an A record or a CNAME to work with their Service Bus functionality.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David,
Thank you for sharing your requirement. Using custom domains with Windows Azure Service Bus is not currently supported. However, it is among the features that the Service Bus team is considering enabling in the near future. We'll have further information on this when the feature is available for use.

-santosh

Comment: This would be nice to have - we use CNAMEs to group application dependencies together. It would be a great addition to the **Service Bus** configuration page to upload your SSL certificate and assign your custom domain similarly to **Cloud Service** and **API Management**. Is there a [user voice request](http://feedback.azure.com/) for this? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Seven years later... any updates on this? The documentation seems to indicate that this feature is still not available/enabled.